# 'configure' failing with Android NDK standalone toolchain

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, makefile, configure, autoconf

I'm trying to build something with the Android NDK standalone compiler toolchain, but I'm getting this error:

```
Updating bundled third-party dependencies...

bash -c 'mkdir -p output/{debug,release,test}/{FCollada/{FCDocument,FMath,FUtils,FColladaTest/{FCTestAssetManagement,FCTestExportImport,FCTestXRef}},FColladaPlugins/FArchiveXML}'
cp output/libFColladaSD.a ../lib/libFColladaSD.a
cp output/libFColladaSR.a ../lib/libFColladaSR.a

Building SpiderMonkey...

SpiderMonkey build options: --disable-tests         
loading cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for perl5... no
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for c++... arm-linux-androideabi-g++
checking whether the C++ compiler (arm-linux-androideabi-g++  ) works... no
configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C++ compiler cannot create executables.
ERROR: SpiderMonkey build failed
```

This is what the `config.log` says: http://pastebin.com/5AFZG4CX

My `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is set as follows:

```
afeder@ubuntu:~/android/0ad/build/workspaces$ echo $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7-crystax-4
```

What might be the cause or how do I debug it? Thank you.

Comment: What does `config.log` say? Can you upload it?

Comment: This is what the config.log says: http://pastebin.com/5AFZG4CX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me this looks broken:

```
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Here's how I'd set up the environment for my Android NDK build:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}-g++
```

... other binutils as needed ...

```
export NDK=/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7-crystax-4
export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
PATH=$PATH:$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
```

Make sure and add `--sysroot=$SYSROOT` to `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, and/or `CXXFLAGS`.

Now you need to tell the spidermonkey `configure` that you are cross compiling:

```
./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi
```

Comment: `--sysroot=$SYSROOT` also needs to go to the preprocessor flags variable `CPPFLAGS`. Please update your answer with that for an upvote .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it can't find `arm-linux-androideabi-g++`. Try searching for it in the NDK folder and adding the directory to your `PATH`.

Mine is here:

```
ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
```

Comment: That was my thought too, but `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` does appear to be in my `PATH` and if I just run `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` off the command-line, it finds it well enough.

Comment: Do you have an `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` environment variable set?

Comment: Yes, `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` is set to `/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7-crystax-4`.